# How to change the sequence of entries in TreeMap based on the 'Key'

Tags: java, sorting, treemap

I have a `Map<String,List<UserVO>> studentsByCountry = new TreeMap<String,List<UserVO>>();`

It displays like :

```
key=CountryA , value = List<UserVO>
key=CountryB , value = List<UserVO>
key=CountryC , value = List<UserVO>
```

Can I reshuffle this `Map` so that I display according to the displayOrder of the countries. Display order is countryC=1, countryB=2 & countryA=3. I want to display like

```
key=CountryC , value = List<UserVO>
key=CountryB , value = List<UserVO>
key=CountryA , value = List<UserVO>
```

One option is to append the sortOrderNumber to the key. `For example 1_CountryC, 2_CountryB & 3_CountryA`

Can I do it via conventional Java?

Comment: How is the TreeMap supposed to know which goes first and which goes last? There is nothing in the key that suggests that CountryC should be the lowest element.

Comment: so appending with 1_, 2_, etc is the only option?

Comment: No not the only one. But you need to have a rule to establish which is the order, and then implement that as a Comparator which you would pass into the contructor of the TreeMap.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `new TreeMap<String, List<UserVO>>();`

```
Map<String, List<UserVO>> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
sortedMap.putAll(myMap);
```

Inspired from: [Sorting Descending order: Java Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923167/sorting-descending-order-java-map)

> If you want an unordered map you should use `HashMap`

TreeMap in Java is one of the implementations of the Map interface. How it differs from the other implementation HashMap is that unlike `HashMap which is unordered`, `TreeMap is Sorted`.

Comment: .reverseOrder() means descending order. I want to keep it dynamic. So sometimes if sortOrder defined is DBAC, then we display: CountryD, CountryB, CountryA, CountryC

Comment: [CountryD, CountryB, CountryA, CountryC] is not a sortOrder, you should implement HashMap. OR you need to add any prefix to define an order.

Comment: yes, as I said, One option is to append the sortOrderNumber to the key. For example 1_CountryC, 2_CountryB & 3_CountryA